# Getting strange strings in C after reading getc from file

Tags: c, char, malloc

I am getting strange strings after the first iteration. I suspect it could be because of string termination, but I am not sure how to fix it. Or I might be using malloc the wrong way.

I am happy for any hints.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "file_reader.h"

/**
 *  Opens a text file and reads the file. The text of the file is stored
    *  in memory in blocks of size blockSize. The linked list with the text is
    *  returned by the function. Each block should contain only complete words.
    *  If a word is split by the end of the block, the last letters should be
    *  moved into the next text block. Each text block must be NULL-terminated.
    *  If the reading of the file fails, the program should return a meaningful
    *  error message.
    */

int getFileSize(FILE* file) {
    FILE* endOfFile = file;
    fseek(endOfFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    long int size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    return (int) size;
}

LinkedList* read_text_file(const char* filename, int blockSize) {
    int globalByteCounter = 0;
    LinkedList*   list = LinkedList_create();
    int blockByteCounter;
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    int fileSize = getFileSize(fp);
    char* tokPointer = malloc(sizeof(getc(fp)));

    char* block = malloc(sizeof strcat("",""));

    //Loop for blocks in list
    while (globalByteCounter <= fileSize) {

        blockByteCounter = 0;
        char* word = malloc(sizeof(blockSize));

        //loop for each block
        while(blockByteCounter<blockSize) {
            char tok;

            //Building a word
            do {
                strcat(word, tokPointer);
                tok = (char) getc(fp);
                tokPointer=&tok;
                blockByteCounter++;
            }while (isalpha(tok));

            //Does this word still fit the block?
            if (blockByteCounter + strlen(word) < blockSize) {
                strcat(block, word);
                //Setze Wort zurück und füge Sonderzeicehen an
                word = strcpy(word,tokPointer);
            } else {
                strcpy(block,word);
            }
        }
        globalByteCounter += blockByteCounter;
        LinkedList_append(list, block);
        free(word);
    }
    LinkedList_append(list,block);
    fclose(fp);
    free(block);
    free(tokPointer);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: You are using the `sizeof` function completely wrong. You need to do some research on how that actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with the code. Let me tackle a few of them:

`sizeof(getc(fp))`

This is the same as applying `sizeof` on the return type of `getc`. In your case, what you are doing here is `sizeof(int)`. That's not what you want.

Assuming that you have a text file, where the size of what you want to read is a number in ASCII, what you are looking for is the good old `fscanf`.

Similar here:

```
strcat("","")
```

but actually worse. `strcat("a", "b")` does not return `"ab"`. It attempts to concatenate `"b"` onto `"a"` and returns the address of `a`, which is pretty bad because not only it doesn't do what you want, but also attempts to modify the string `"a"`. You can't modify string literals.

`blockByteCounter` is not initialized.

And you got your hunch right:

```
char* word = malloc(sizeof(blockSize));
```

If you don't initialize `word` as an empty string, when you try to concatenate `tokPointer` onto it you'll run through a non-terminated string. Not only that, but `tokPointer` is also *not initialized*!

I'm also not sure why you are trying to use `strcat` to build a word. You don't need all those pointers. Once you know the required size of your buffer, you can 1) simply use `fscanf` to read one word; or 2) use `fgetc` with a good old simple counter `i` to put each letter into the buffer array, and  then terminate it with `0` before printing.